# What properties does Node.js express's Error object expose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

I would like to know what are the functions that the Error object of nodejs express exposes for use in error handling?

A `console.log` of an error call `new Error('NotFound')` is showing only `[Error: NotFound]`.
Is this because the `.toString()` method is overriden?
How do I find the properties and functions exposed by these objects?

Comment: Check out the answer here: http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/errors/what-is-the-error-object

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `Error` object is actually a native object provided by `V8`, rather than by `node.js` or `express`.

The property that will most likely be of the most use to you is `stack`. E.g.,

```
console.log(new Error('NotFound').stack);
```

There are other properties available as well, such as `name` and `message`. You can read up on them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error). Just be aware that those docs are for Mozilla's JavaScript engine, so don't count on anything flagged as `Non-standard` to work in `node.js`.